# <br/> height adjustment to align the same height with other lines

Tags: html, css

The format of the line 4 and line 5 is too big. I want to make it the same height as the other line.

```html
<td>
  <strong><em>This is a example</em></strong>
  <br /><br />Line 1<br /><br />

  <ul>
    <li>Line 2<br />Content 2</li>
    <br />
    <li>Line 3<br />Content 3</li>
    <br />
    <li>Line 4<br />Content 4</li>

  </ul>

  <span style="line-height:0px;"><br></span>
  <strong><em>b) Line 5</em></strong>
  <br/><br/>Content 5
</td>
```

**Screenshot of issue:**

[image]

Comment: Right click and inspect-element. That will show you where the margins/padding are. Also, avoid using `<br>` tags for vertical spacing. And don't place them where they don't belong (inside a `<ul>`)... Maybe try something like this in your css`<style>li{margin-bottom:10px;padding-bottom:10px}</style>` Also, adding borders to thing can help a lot when you're trying to figure out a layout on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
           <td>  

            <strong><em>This is a example</em></strong> 
            <br>
            Line 1

      <ul>                 

      <li>Line 2<br />Content 2</li>  

            <br />  

      <li>Line 3<br />Content 3</li>  

            <br />  

             <li>Line 4<br />Content 4</li>  

            </ul>  

            <strong><em>b)Line 5</em></strong>  
            <br><br>Content 5  

        </td>  
</table>
```

and stop using IE , using chrome or firefox

Answer (score 0):

That big space below "content 4" is combination of:

- The `<br/>`
- The `<ul>...</ul>` have top and bottom spaces.

Either remove the `<br/>` in line 4, or remove the bottom space of the `<ul>...</ul>` like this:

```
<ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    ...
</ul>
```